# Connect one observable to another existing one

Tags: system.reactive

I have two observables, one that produces elements, other that is a [Subject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh211669%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) that subscribers are subscribed to. I would like subscribers to get what comes through the first one. One way is to do the following.

```
 first.Subscribe(a => second.OnNext(a);
```

Somehow I only like to Subscribe at the final end, not to Subscribe just to pipe one to the other. I am curious if there is any Rx extension that allows something like that before I go about writing my own.

Comment: See if this (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21836818/subscribing-to-a-future-observable) helps you.

Answer (score 2):

This works for me:

```
var subject = new Subject<long>();

subject.Subscribe(x => Console.WriteLine(x));

var observable = Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1.0));

observable.Subscribe(subject);
```

I get the series of values from the `Interval` observable from the `Console.WriteLine` observer.